# Python3 - string / integer error

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I included the short code followed by the error response at the bottom. I am attempting to create a new variable (agep) by taking an input variable (age) and adding a value of 2 to it to obtain a numerical result. Why am I getting the error and what would be the proper fix to print my desired result?

```
   print ("Welcome")
   myVar = "Hello"
   myName = input ("What is your name?") 
   print (myVar + " " + myName)
   age = input ("What is your age?")
   print ("You are " +age)
   agep = age + 2
   print ("You will be " + agep + " in 730 days")
```

> Error: , line 8, in 
>       agep = age + 2 TypeError: must be str, not int

Answer (score 0):

your `age` variable is being read as a string. try explicitly telling Python to read it as an int when creating `agep`:

```
print ("Welcome")
myVar = "Hello"
myName = input ("What is your name?") 
print (myVar + " " + myName)
age = input ("What is your age?")
print ("You are " +age)
# Here, transform age to int so that you can add 2 (another int)
agep = int(age) + 2
# Here, turn it back into a string to be able to concatenate with other strings
print ("You will be " + str(agep) + " in 730 days")
```

Here is some [background reading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) on python data types that you might want to take a look at

Answer (score 0):

Because Python doesn't sum String and Integer value:
So if you want to add your age you have to make `age` variable to the Integer:
like this: `int(age)` (for adding `2` with `age` variable).

And finally, for printing, you have to change your `integer variable` into `string` again, like this: `str(agep)`.

and your code be:

```
 print ("Welcome")
 myVar = "Hello"
 myName = input ("What is your name?") 
 print (myVar + " " + myName)
 age = input("What is your age?")
 print ("You are " +age)
 agep = int(age) + 2
 print ("You will be " + str(agep) + " in 730 days")
```